# How to unwrap guard statement in its body?

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire

my error statement is :

variable declared in 'guard condition' is not usable in its body

and my code is:

```
 extension ViewController {
  func uploadImage(image: UIImage, progress: (percent: Float) -> Void,
                   completion: (tags: [String], colors: [PhotoColor]) -> Void) {
    guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) else {

      Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        "http://api.imagga.com/v1/content",
        headers: ["Authorization" : "Basic xxx"],
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
          multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "imagefile",
            fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
          }
```

the above is one a part of the program.

the error occurs in the line contains "data: imageData"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're confusing `guard let ... else` with `if let`.

Comment: i second that @EricAya

Comment: so what modifications should i make?

Comment: ohh..you have to return control from else part & perform operation after else block.

Comment: move the code in the `else{..}` block outside, replace that with error handling and `return`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this **guard** example:

```
guard let variable = optionalVariable else { return }
// Variable is safe to use here
```

And this **if** example:

```
if let variable = optionalVariable {
    // Variable is safe to use here 
}
```

In your case, you're mixing both concepts. You're using the **guard** as a **if** statement. You could change your guard to an if, or move the code outside of the else block.

The **guard** statement can be a bit confusing! Consider its use like the **continue** statement inside of a loop.

Comment: Well, the idea is that the guard statement shouldn't confuse you... OP should have wondered what that "else" behind the guard is good for...